PL SQL calculate delta and transpose the result
I'm using PL SQL and I have the following sample data:
(I have an ID and an accumulated daily counter, assuming I need to check only recent 7 days (Nov 26th till Dec 3rd in this case))

I want to achieve two things:

calculating the daily value (added here as a refference as a 4th column)
transposing the daily value  for the combination of ID and reference date (today)
the result would look something like that:


the same would be for more IDs and more dates, but let's assume that the 7 days range remains, but the process can be executed daily of course (tomorrow, for example, it will examine the dates - Nov 27th till Dec 4th etc.)

Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?

This question is similar to: Convert a set of columns into rows in ORACLE SQL. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Can you also show us your current code attempt?

Have you row for every date for every id or there gaps in date?

Convert the date to an offset from the current day and use LAG to find the delta and then PIVOT:
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         TRUNC(SYSDATE) - dt AS day,
         value - LAG(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt) AS delta
  FROM   table_name
)
PIVOT (
  SUM(delta) FOR day IN (
    0 AS value_0,
    1 AS value_1,
    2 AS value_2,
    3 AS value_3,
    4 AS value_4,
    5 AS value_5,
    6 AS value_6,
    7 AS value_7
  )
)

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, dt, value) AS
SELECT 10, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 7,    74  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 6,   651 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 5, 12416 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 4, 12800 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 3, 12802 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 2, 12804 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1, 13624 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 0, 13752 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 7,    88  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 6,    95 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 5,    96 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 4,  1111 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 3,  1111 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 2,  1200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1,  1350 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 0,  1350 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



ID
VALUE_0
VALUE_1
VALUE_2
VALUE_3
VALUE_4
VALUE_5
VALUE_6
VALUE_7




10
128
820
2
2
384
11765
577
null


20
0
150
89
0
1015
1
7
null



fiddle
